# Substrate-node-template build fail for Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10

Tags: substrate-node-template, wsl, windows

I was following the beginner's tutorial here: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/create-your-first-substrate-chain/

When I get to cargo build --release I get the following error:

```sh
thread 'main' panicked at 'failed to execute command: No such file or directory (os error 2)',
/home/hidden-username/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tikv-jemalloc-sys-0.4.3+5.2.1-patched.2/build.rs:334:19
```

I'm running Windows 10 but operating my node on a WSL `lsb_release`.

Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (focal)

```
installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.60.0 (7737e0b5c 2022-04-04)
```

I ran a full Backtrace, if anyone cares to take a look:

```sh
thread 'main' panicked at 'failed to execute command: No such file or directory (os error 2)', /home/user-name/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tikv-jemalloc-sys-0.4.3+5.2.1-patched.2/build.rs:334:19
stack backtrace:
   0:     0x7f8453e871ad - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::libunwind::trace::hee598835bc88d35b
                               at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/std/src/../../backtrace/src/backtrace/libunwind.rs:93:5
   1:     0x7f8453e871ad - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::trace_unsynchronized::h9cdc730ba5cf5d72
                               at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/std/src/../../backtrace/src/backtrace/mod.rs:66:5
   2:     0x7f8453e871ad - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print_fmt::h75aeaf7ed30e43fa
                               at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:66:5
   3:     0x7f8453e871ad - <std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::DisplayBacktrace as core::fmt::Display>::fmt::h606862f787600875
                               at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:45:22
   4:     0x7f8453eaa37c - core::fmt::write::he803f0f418caf762
                               at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/core/src/fmt/mod.rs:1190:17
   5:     0x7f8453e827c8 - std::io::Write::write_fmt::h70bc45872f37e7bb
                               at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/std/src/io/mod.rs:1657:15
   6:     0x7f8453e89487 - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::h64d038cf8ac3e13e
                               at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:48:5
   7:     0x7f8453e89487 - std::sys_common::backtrace::print::h359300b4a7fccf65
                               at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:35:9
   8:     0x7f8453e89487 - std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}::hf51be35e2f510149
                               at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/std/src/panicking.rs:295:22
   9:     0x7f8453e89150 - std::panicking::default_hook::h03ca0f22e1d2d25e
                               at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/std/src/panicking.rs:314:9
  10:     0x7f8453e89bd9 - std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook::h3b7380e99b825b63
                               at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/std/src/panicking.rs:698:17
  11:     0x7f8453e898c7 - std::panicking::begin_panic_handler::{{closure}}::h8e849d0710154ce0
                               at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/std/src/panicking.rs:588:13
  12:     0x7f8453e87674 - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_end_short_backtrace::hedcdaddbd4c46cc5
                               at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:138:18
  13:     0x7f8453e895d9 - rust_begin_unwind
                               at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/std/src/panicking.rs:584:5
  14:     0x7f8453e09493 - core::panicking::panic_fmt::he1bbc7336d49a357
                               at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/core/src/panicking.rs:143:14
  15:     0x7f8453e0e179 - build_script_build::execute::h343d6afa2e0ceef7
  16:     0x7f8453e0df86 - build_script_build::run::h77c5c3d9911c5b0d
  17:     0x7f8453e0cc93 - build_script_build::main::h58a32d56a136094c
  18:     0x7f8453e11cd3 - core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once::hbbb738d0cd945cf7
  19:     0x7f8453e11a69 - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::hf9dce89d7f8aca0b
  20:     0x7f8453e11a39 - std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}::h5e39e3c0ddde7c39
  21:     0x7f8453e86891 - core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnOnce<A> for &F>::call_once::hb7014f43484a8b4e
                               at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:259:13
  22:     0x7f8453e86891 - std::panicking::try::do_call::h7bc9dc436daeb8c7
                               at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/std/src/panicking.rs:492:40
  23:     0x7f8453e86891 - std::panicking::try::h653d68a27ff5f175
                               at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/std/src/panicking.rs:456:19
  24:     0x7f8453e86891 - std::panic::catch_unwind::h9d739f9f59895e68
                               at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/std/src/panic.rs:137:14
  25:     0x7f8453e86891 - std::rt::lang_start_internal::{{closure}}::hf006f2bc7ce22bbe
                               at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/std/src/rt.rs:128:48
  26:     0x7f8453e86891 - std::panicking::try::do_call::hfb39d6df61a2e69f
                               at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/std/src/panicking.rs:492:40
  27:     0x7f8453e86891 - std::panicking::try::h13e2d225134958ac
                               at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/std/src/panicking.rs:456:19
  28:     0x7f8453e86891 - std::panic::catch_unwind::h3bd49b5a5dfb1a50
                               at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/std/src/panic.rs:137:14
  29:     0x7f8453e86891 - std::rt::lang_start_internal::h2ba92edce36c035e
                               at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/std/src/rt.rs:128:20
  30:     0x7f8453e11a21 - std::rt::lang_start::hc141b7822a458dac
  31:     0x7f8453e0ea53 - main
  32:     0x7f8453b940b3 - __libc_start_main
  33:     0x7f8453e09c6e - _start
  34:                0x0 - <unknown>
```

Comment: Have you checked out the code base on windows and then opened via mnt from wsl?

Comment: Do you have `make` installed? There are similar questions already asked about this.

Comment: Yeah, should be the missing `make` tool.
From the backtrace you can see that it is the `main` calling `run` with some params.

The only places this happens is [here](https://github.com/tikv/jemallocator/blob/2706fb3874e075eca51af7f672d228ce28d5c475/jemalloc-sys/build.rs#L266), [here](https://github.com/tikv/jemallocator/blob/2706fb3874e075eca51af7f672d228ce28d5c475/jemalloc-sys/build.rs#L274) and in other two places. All of these are calling `make` tool. 

`apt install make` should solve your problem

Comment: Cheers guys, that was the issue. much appreciated for the assist.